# How to get the long version of a float?

Tags: python, double

I am trying to solve problem 26 from Project Euler and I am wondering how to show the long version of a floating-point number.  For example if we have 1/19 how do we get 64, 128, or more digits of that float in python?  An even more useful builtin function would be that returns the numbers after the decimal until it repeats?  I know that floats technically store decimal points up until a certain point and then round of to keep things efficient, memory-wise, but is there a way to overload that until you get the repeating part of it?  I would guess that such a function would give an exception to an irrational number but is there a function that works for at least rational numbers?

Comment: Floats don't work like that. You'll need to avoid using them.

Comment: what is "problem 26"?

Comment: From project euler

Comment: Yeah, you need to provide **all the information about your question here**. They have to be self-contained. In any case, that problem is not going to be solvable with `float` objects

Comment: The third-party [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/) module supports arbitrary-precision floating-point math.

Answer (score 1):

See the Decimal datatype.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 64
print(Decimal(1) / Decimal(19))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: This won't actually help with the underlying problem, though, because that problem is about repeating decimal representations, and you can't tell the period of a repeating decimal just by looking at a finite approximation.

Comment: Not sure why you're saying this don't solve the problem unless it was edited.  This module can be used to get a correct decimal representation of 1/19 to 64 or 128 decimal places.  If he wants to use that to solve a larger underlying problem, he can write the code.

Comment: The *underlying* problem is [Project Euler problem 26](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26), and getting 64 or 128 digits doesn't help with that. The question exhibits an XY problem.

Comment: And what about that problem prevents him from using this module?  Getting 64 or 128 or 5000 digits accurately absolute does help with that and it's hard to do in python without a module like this.

Comment: @FredS: There is no way to tell the period of a repeating decimal from a finite approximation.

Comment: Depends.  The problem as I read it is for d<1000.  Which I'm guessing you likely can solve with a large enough finite approximation.  Easy enough to find out for a range that small.

Comment: At the time of writing my response, @Fateh did not specify where Problem 26 was from, so I just provided an answer to his question which was how to get a finite number of digits of a float.

Comment: Right but I did read the problem, and if you told me to go solve problem 26 by writing a python script, I would use this module to do it.  I've yet to hear anyone propose a better way to go about it.

Comment: @FredS: Perform long division until you detect a cycle, pretty much the same way you would do it by hand in elementary school. (You don't need to save the actual division results, only the remainders, though.)

Comment: Yeah I guess that works too but I'm thinking a good bit more lines of code for the solution.  If someone asks me to find prime numbers from 1 to 1000 I think I will write much different code than if they ask me to find from 1 to 100 trillion.  In the latter case performance matters a lot, in the first case it matters very little.